# Is Selenium2 WebDriver executeScript run after window.onload?

Tags: javascript, testing, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Can I assume if using the Selenium2 WebDriver executeScript method, my script would be after window.onload?

e.g. after all DOM elements/images are loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can assume as it will get executed after entire page loaded in browser

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. If you're using the `executeScript()` method after a `get()` call, the answer is "maybe". WebDriver tries to block on calls to `get()`, but there may be JavaScript code that will still run after the onload fires (consider the case where the code in the onload event handler uses setTimeout() to defer execution), which means the DOM may still be manipulated. If you're using `executeScript()` after clicking on a link that causes a navigation, there's even less chance that the execution will wait until the page is completely loaded, since clicks are asynchronous, and there's no guarantee WebDriver will be able to wait for the page to load.

Comment: do you know how to run `executeScript` before `window.onload`? I'm facing a problem that can't run executeScript because of web page is very heavy using ajax to communicate with server, which caught `executeScript` keep waiting and waiting...